# Is $\lim \frac {f(x_n)}{x_n} = \frac{f(\lim x_n)}{x_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, and $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ continuous.  We know that $\lim f(x_n) = f(\lim x_n)$.  Is $\lim \frac {f(x_n)}{x_n} = \frac{f(\lim x_n)}{x_n}$?

If not: In addition to a counterexample, can you explain how the proof used to show $\lim f(x_n) = f(\lim x_n)$ breaks down when applied over $\frac{}{x_n}$?

---

**Update:** Thank you to the commenters. Is it accurate to say:

1. If $\frac{f(\lim x_n)}{x_n}$ is defined and equal for all $n$, which happens if and only if either $x_n$ is constant or $f(\lim x_n) = 0$, then this value must equal $\lim \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}$.
2. Otherwise, we can only say $\lim \frac {f(x_n)}{x_n} = \frac{f(\lim x_n)}{\lim x_n}$?

---

One of the commenters (JonathanZ) asks: *Where did this question come from?* I was working on a proof, which I've posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606231/verify-if-every-open-interval-has-x-neq-0-fx-0-then-fn-0), and discovered an error (marked as Equation (1) in the link), which sent me into quite a tailspin trying to resolve.  At some point, I extracted the issue I was confused about, and extracted it to this question.

Essentially, if we have a sequence $(x_n) \to 0, x_n \neq 0, f(x_n) = 0$, we can conclude $\lim \frac {f(x_n)}{x_n} = 0$.  I believe that to be correct.  Where I hit a snag is if $f(x_n)$ isn't necessarily equal to zero, just arbitrarily close - what can we conclude? Again, the context is at Equation 1 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606231/verify-if-every-open-interval-has-x-neq-0-fx-0-then-fn-0).  Perhaps I need to ask a better question, or better formulate what I'm struggling with.  Any help with that itself would be appreciated.

Comment: As long as there is no follow-up question, I would say that the proof breaks down semantically.

Comment: Put $g: x\mapsto f(x)/x$. Conclude.

Comment: Let $\ell=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(x_n)$, you are asking if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}=\frac{\ell}{x_n}$, that's weird isn't it ?

Comment: No, it is $$
\lim \frac{{f(x_n )}}{{x_n }} = \frac{{f(\lim x_n )}}{{\lim x_n }}.
$$

Comment: @AndrewZhang I do not follow - can you elaborate?

Comment: @SRobertJames If $g(x)=f(x)/x$, what do you know about $\lim g(x_n)$? (I would assume $x_n \not \to 0$.)

Comment: The last is likely to be $0/0$, so, no, you can’t say that.

Comment: This is a weird question. And having seen you post quite a few questions, all of which seemed to be quite sensible, even if they were kind of poking around some of the more technical points of analysis, I'm really curious where it comes from. As several commenters are indicating, it's odd that one side depends on $n$ and the other side does not.

Comment: I've updated the question to provide context (and a link) explaining where it comes from.  Also, can you explain what you mean by "poking around some of the more technical points of analysis?"

Comment: Interesting, and thanks. And I just meant that it seemed like you were taking a first course in analysis, and were working really hard to make sure you understood every book and corner of your proofs. No criticism intended, it's just that I wondered if this was an XY situation, where you say you want to do X, but it's really in service of accomplishing Y, and maybe you don't really need X at all. So maybe people can understand this question better by referring to the question you linked.