# Verify: If every open interval has $x \neq 0, f(x) = 0$, then $f^{(n)} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, intuition, smooth-functions

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that for any open interval $I$ containing zero, there exists $x \in I, x \neq 0$ with $f(x) = 0$.  Show that $f^{(n)}(0)$ (the nth-derivative of $f$ at zero), if defined, is zero.

*Please help me fix this proof; see Equation (1) and its error.*

**Proof:** Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence converging to zero such that $x_n \neq 0, f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.  Such a sequence always exists, for example, by picking appropriate $x_n$ in $(-1/n, 1/n)$.  If $f'(0)$ is defined, $f$ is continuous at zero, and $f(0) = f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n) = 0$.

Likewise, since for all $n \in \mathbb N, x_n \neq 0$ and $\frac {f(x_n)}{x_n} - 0$, if $f'(0)$ is defined, $$\begin{align*}f'(0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(h) - f(0)}h \\ &= \lim \frac {f(x_n)}{x_n} \\ &= 0.\end{align*}$$

For all $p \in \mathbb N$, if $f^{(p)}(0) = 0$ and $f^{(p+1)}(0)$ is defined, then $f^{(p)}$ is continuous at zero and defined on an open interval $I_p$ including zero.  Restrict $(x_n)$ to the subsequence in $I_p$.  Then $f^{(p+1)}(0) = 0$, since $$\begin{align*}f^{(p+1)}(0) &= \lim_n \frac {f^{(p)}(0 + x_n) - f^{(p)}(0)}{x_n} \\
&= \lim_n \frac {f^{(p)}(x_n)}{x_n} \tag{1} \\
&= 0.\end{align*}$$

*I'm unable to justify Line 1* unless *$f^{(p)}$ is zero on an* interval *containing zero, not just a point. I tried expanding $f^{(p)}$ to the limit definition, and using double limits, but this seemed to complicate things without getting anywhere.  Can you guide me here?*

By definition of derivative, if $f^{(p+1)}(0)$ is defined, then $f^{(p)}(0)$ must also be defined.  Therefore, we have by induction that if $f^{(p)}(0)$ is defined, it equals zero.

**Discussion:**

Intuitively, this means that if a function that is *arbitrarily close to flat* at a point, to the extent that it is smooth at that point, its derivatives must vanish.  This holds for both functions that *flatten out simply*, such as $x \mapsto x^n$ as well as for functions with *never ending small ripples*, such as $x \mapsto 0$ if $x = 0$ otherwise $x^n \sin(1/x)$.  (This comment is not meant to convey rigor, but to give an intuitive sense of the result.)

Comment: Change your induction hypothesis for "$f^{(p)}=0$ in a neighborhood of $x$" and it'll work. Also, you can do without the sequence $(x_n)$. Indeed, if $f^{(p)}=0$ around $x$, then $f^{(p)}(x+h)=0$ for $h$ small enough and the limit is $0$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien But I haven't shown (and in fact am not convinced of) the base case, that $f' = 0$ for a neighborhood around $0$.

Comment: Note that in order for the $n$ th derivative of $f$ to be defined, you need to have $f$ differentiable $n-1$ times on a small neighborhood $U$ of the origin; but then use Rolle theorem and induction to show that the derivatives of $f$ up to order $n-1$ have a zero on any interval containing zero and included in $U$ so you conclude for the $n$ th derivative as you do for the first since the $n-1$ derivative has same property as $f$ as zeroes go

Comment: @Conrad Um... Took me some time to write up a proof for which I saw only after the fact that it is the same as in your comment!

Comment: @Stinking no problem as the above is something quite standard so no wonder we used same idea

Answer (score 2):

If $n$th derivative exists at $x=0$, then all derivatives up to $n-1$st exist in some neighbourhood of zero. Let's restrict ourselves to that neighbourhood.

Per the conditions of the problem, one can find the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ converging to $0$ such that $f(x_i)=0$. WLOG we can assume $x_1>x_2>x_3>\ldots>0$.

As per Rolle's theorem, this gives rise to a sequence $x_1'>x_2'>x_3'>\ldots>0$ converging to $0$ such that $f'(x_i')=0$. ($x_i'$ is between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$). Repeating the same argument $n-1$ times, we find a sequence $x_1^{(n-1)}>x_2^{(n-1)}>\ldots>0$ converging to $0$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(x_i^{(n-1)})=0$. This implies that $f^{(n-1)}(0)=0$ and, ultimately, that $f^{(n)}(0)=\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x_i^{(n-1)})-f^{(n-1)}(0)}{x_i^{(n-1)}}=\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{0-0}{x_i^{(n-1)}}=0$.

Comment: Why should all derivatives exist *in some neighbourhood* of $0$  and not only at $0$ alone?  Define $\phi(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $\phi(x)=0$ otherwise.  Now define $$f(x)=\begin{cases}  \phi(x),&\text{if $x$ rational;}\\ x^n, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Your function is not even continuous except at $x=0$. Thus, $f'(x)$ only exists at $x=0$. What is then $f''(0):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(h)-f'(0)}{h}$ ? (The RHS is not defined for any $h$.) Thus, it is a very standard requirement for the existence of $f^{(n)}(x)$ at a point $x=x_0$ that $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ exists in some neighbourhood of $x_0$. (I appreciate, strictly speaking, that it would be enough to require only that $x_0$ is an *accumulation point* of the domain of $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ but this would be very unusual and would need to be called out explicitly in the problem statement.)

Comment: Now, I can also appreciate that your definition of derivatives may differ from mine. E.g. you may say that, if $f(x+h)=f(x)+a_1h+a_2h^2/2!+a_3h^3/3!+\ldots+a_nh^n/n!+o(h^n)$, then *define* $f^{(n)}(x):=a_n$ (with a proof of uniqueness) - and then your argument holds, and I wonder whether the entire statement would be true. But - this definition is not the "elementary" one from Calculus, and is not equivalent to it ... except if those derivatives are defined in some neighbourhood, where the Taylor expansion provides the proof of the equivalence.